# unix group write permission not working as expected

Tags: unix, permissions

Sorry for this very basic question but I cannot find any answer.

I've got a user cldprod which is in primary group 'cldprod' and in secondary group 'jboss'
I've got another user jboss which is in primary group 'jboss'.

'cldprod' user cannot removes file with those permissions :

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jboss jboss xxxxxx
rm: cannot remove `xxxxx': Permission denied
```

I don't understand why (as 'cldprod' is in group 'jboss' and 'jboss' has write permission on the file).

My /etc/passwd :

```
cldprod:x:500:501:xxxxxx
jboss:x:501:502:xxxxxx
```

My /etc/group :

```
cldprod:x:501:
jboss:x:502:cldprod
```

My infos :

```
 $ uname -a
Linux ip-xxxxx xxxxxx.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon May 6 18:04:41 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove a file (directory entry), you need write permissions on *the directory containing it*, not the file itself.

Write permission on the file only allows you to modify the content of the file and its metadata, such as permissions.

Comment: OK, I know this but my directory is also writable for the group jboss : drwxrwxr-x 2 jboss jboss 4096 Jun 26 14:01 MyDir

Comment: @jmcollin92: what does `id cldprod` report?

Comment: $ id cldprod
uid=500(cldprod) gid=501(cldprod) groups=501(cldprod),502(jboss)